# Magento2 Place Order Without billing address and payment Method

Tags: magento2, checkout

i don't want billing address on my checkout page and i achieved this but when product price is 0 billing address not showing and payment method also not showing i want to place order without both billing address and payment method.

Answer (score 1):

IN magento2, you cannot checkout without selecting any Payment method.

*And if you don't want to select show shipping address then you have to create [Virtual Products](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-virtual.html).
If your cart only has the virtual product at cart then checkout does not show shipping address. Otherwise, you must have to select the Shipping address.*

If you want that your checkout does not have any payment and billing then you have to break Magento architecture oR you have to create dummy payment and  dummy billing method for checkout.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Billing Address and not a Shipping Address?

Comment: Shipping address is not required for virtual products